# Save every file to different location with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with the following:
I found VBA code to copy data from Excel sheet depending on the data, then put this data in new file and save it.

I need something to make every file in this code saved in a different place depending on the name of the filter the code is using to separate the data from the original sheet.

ex: if the name in filter "book" I want the file saved in folder with "book" name, if the filter name is "story" I want the file saved in folder with "story" name ... etc.

i will attach the code i have

```
Sub parse_data()
Dim lr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim vcol, i As Integer
Dim icol As Long
Dim myarr As Variant
Dim title As String
Dim titlerow As Integer
Dim DT As String
Dim WBNAM As String
Dim FilePATH As String
Dim FILEEXT As String


vcol = 7
Set ws = Sheets("ER")
lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
title = "A1:G1"
titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
icol = ws.Columns.Count
ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"

Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select


For i = 2 To lr
On Error Resume Next
If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
End If
Next
myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
ws.Columns(icol).Clear
For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
Workbooks.Add
Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
Else
Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
Windows("Book1").Activate
End If
ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit

Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1:S1").Delete
Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("g:k").Delete
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

WBNAM = "_ER_"
DT = Format(CStr(Now), "DDMMYYYY")
FilePathe = "C:\Users\DODO\Desktop\New folder\"
FILEEXT = ".xlsx"


ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FilePathe & DT & WBNAM & myarr(i) & "" & FILEEXT
ActiveWindow.Close
Next
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
ws.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: **Option Explicit** will do some good here

Comment: @urdearboy that should be automatic from the little I understand...

Comment: It's not what I mean :(

Answer (score 1):

Well first point is you define “filepath” and then use “filepathe”...

If the filename is something like book_29 then you could use find() to get the postion of the underscore and left() with find() to get just book.